# Run 3 Python Lines of Code Asynchronous without order

Tags: python, asynchronous

Ok so I have a function that calls an API and waits for the response. I am using threading in order to parallelize calling requests during building the DataFrame. The same function gets called later many times but only with 1 item. So iterator is actually a list of just 1 element, hence no threading happens.

I want to use something like asyncio to allow the 3 lines of code to execute regardless of order (not wait each other) if iterator length is 1.

Minimal Code:

```
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import thread_map
import pandas as pd

def func(x):
  return x+1

df = pd.DataFrame()
iterator = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df["foo"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
df["bar"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
df["foobar"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
```

What I want to do (wrong syntax for async):

```
if len(iterator) == 1:
    with async:
        df["foo"] = func(iterator[0])
        df["bar"] = func(iterator[0])
        df["foobar"] = func(iterator[0])
else:
    df["foo"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
    df["bar"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
    df["foobar"] = thread_map(func, iterator, max_workers=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that works

```
df["foo"], df["bar"], df["foobar"] = thread_map(func, iterator * 3, max_workers=3)
```